# Cython module not found when called by other python files

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am using cpython to detect all cameras attached to the computer, and return the device information. I have successfully run the program in below by simply calling its file name in terminal. (`device` is the C++ file I generated through setup.py):

```py
import device

def get_device_dict():
    print("hello")
    res = {}

    device_list = device.getDeviceList()
    index = 0

    for name in device_list:
        res[index] = name
        index += 1
    return res

get_device_dict()
```

However, when I try to call the function from another file (camera.py based on the directory structure shown in below) by importing it, problem occurs as it says there is a failure to import the C++ generated package.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'device'
```

Here is my directory:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just made some attempts and find it is running properly from outer directory. The problem is about me running the django framework. The django framework cannot detect the cython module.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).